# How to modularize one LESS stylesheet into multiple stylesheets?

Tags: css, less

I am looking to take my styles.less file (which currently contains 3000 lines of stylesheet code for my entire site) and break it apart into multiple stylesheets, i.e. navigation.less, buttons.less, footer.less, etc.

I suppose I would then @import all of these individual stylesheets into a master stylesheet, such as all.less which would compile/minify down to all.css

One issue I am experiencing with breaking this styles up into individual sheets is that variable references are broken. So for example, if I port over my buttons CSS to buttons.less, my buttons CSS contains references to LESS variables that are defined in styles.less. How do I fix this issue?

Is there a better approach to modularizing my CSS code with LESS? 3000 lines of LESS code is getting completely unmanageable for one file and I need to break it up.

Answer (score 3):

Most people handle this by having two particular files, something like `variables.less` and `mixins.less`.

Then if these are needed in the modules, you use `import-once` instead of just `import` ([for versions prior to the at present upcoming 1.4; at which time `import` *by default* will act as `import-once`](http://www.lesscss.org/#-importing)). You use this in ***both*** the *module* files and in your `all.less`. That way when they are all brought together inside the `all.less` file, the imports only occurs once at the top of the final file, and not for each individual module file loaded.